# Cassandra counters for distinct rows

Tags: cassandra

I was reading about the use of Cassandra's built in counters. But for my use case I have for instance event data of clicks and I need counters for total clicks by campaign and counts of unique users that clicked by campaign. The first is easy but the second I could create a secondary table that is key'ed on the user id and campaign id. But I do not have a way to create a counter on an insert that would need to first read to see if it exists and if so then implement the counter for that type.

I am still reading about Cassandra and hope someone can shed light on the best way to handle this with performance in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a really nice post on the problem you are facing i.e. section about the "Can I maintain a count myself?":

http://www.wentnet.com/blog/?p=24

Basically the idea would be that you insert the unique id's of users into a single row and then count them later. But then again this approach brings it's own maintenance problems.

Comment: Slightly different version of the question but what if I didn't use counters at all for these but instead ran a count select each time requested. I read that count(*) is very expensive but what if the all of the data that I am interested in counting will always share a field in the primary compound key? For instance primary_key(UUID,campaign_id,timestamp,user_id) and then my query would always do select count(*)

Comment: Yes, this is certainly one of the possibilities. If you are running this in some sort of batch etc, it is totally fine, but running this and waiting for it in the gui is not o.k.  Also, depending on the number of records, your requests might time out if you don't adjust cassandra.yaml ... just as an orientation, what would be the number of user_ids?

Comment: Then my query would always do 
    select count(*) from clicks where campaign_id = 2195 
I do not know if I am always limiting my search based on keys will that limit the search to not have to scan the full table and only within the set that contains the campaign_id (200k max compared to billions)

Comment: Unique user_id's within this set would be max around 200k because would just be the set of clickers per campaign.

Comment: 200k might be a bit much for single row, but I would simply partition the campaigns ... into some fixed number of buckets, let's say 10 and put the clicks randomly in. When I would do the count would issue 10 count statements for every "bucket" and there's the click number. There you would have around 20 000 elements which is totally o.k. for counting personally I had up to around 100k in single partition but was always careful with modeling not to go too much over this number.

Comment: Ok, that is the part that I did not understand (the first part of the key is always the actual partition and other compounds are just for sorting but do not affect partition) and was reading through this page here http://datascale.io/cassandra-partitioning-and-clustering-keys-explained/ that mentions what you said above. In your example above if it was instead a composite key (instead of compound) using PRIMARY KEY ((timestamp, campaign_id), user_id) that way including the time stamp in the partition? One thing I cannot find is recommendations for minimum partition sizes?

Comment: In previous versions of cassandra it was ~100k, but I've header it might go up to a million now, but I'm avoiding it heavily because of the pressure on memory. Here is how you do the bucketing `PRIMARY KEY ( (campaign_id, bucket), user_id)` - if you want it unique per user `PRIMARY KEY ((campaign_id, bucket), timestamp)` - if you need all the clicks. When inserting just pick random(1-10) for bucket. When retrieving `count ... where campaign-id = 'cid' and bucket = 1` then for 2, 3, 4 to 10 and you sum up the results. Every bucket falls on different node so it's also easy on the cluster.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand a little more now. If I used the campaign_id without the bucket_id in both the insert and the select it would not right away know which part in the partition to search for is that correct? So if inserted with the bucket but searched without out the additional "and bucket =" it would search more rows because it would not know to go directly to that partition designated correct?